# RavenDB Saga Persister not persisting saga entity

Tags: nservicebus, ravendb

We're using RavenDB saga storage, but the saga data isn't being persisted after the starting message handler. I only see a handful of subscription documents in the database. I'm not sure what to check next. Ideas?

I have a saga:

```
public class BuyerWaitingOnDocumentsDistributor :
    Saga<BuyerDocumentDistributorData>,
    IAmStartedByMessages<DocumentVersionRequiresBuyerSignature>
{
    public void Handle(DocumentVersionRequiresEmployeeSignature message)
    {
        Data.DocumentVersionId = message.DocumentVersionId.Value;
        // Business logic goes here
    }

    // Other handlers & methods here
}
```

and saga entity:

```
public class BuyerDocumentDistributorData : IContainSagaData
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Originator { get; set; }
    public virtual string OriginalMessageId { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid DocumentVersionId { get; set; }
    public virtual EmployeeId[] AuthorizedToSign { get; set; }
}
```

and saga finder:

```
    public class BuyerWaitingOnDocumentsDistributorSagaFinder : 
        IFindSagas<BuyerDocumentDistributorData>.Using<DocumentVersionRequiresBuyerSignature>,
        IFindSagas<BuyerDocumentDistributorData>.Using<DocumentVersionSignedByBuyer>,
        IFindSagas<BuyerDocumentDistributorData>.Using<DocumentVersionNoLongerRequiresSignature>
    {

        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (BuyerWaitingOnDocumentsDistributorSagaFinder));

        public ISagaPersister Persister { get; set; }

        public BuyerDocumentDistributorData FindBy(DocumentVersionRequiresBuyerSignature message)
        {
            return Persister.Get<BuyerDocumentDistributorData>("DocumentVersionId", message.DocumentVersionId.Value);
        }

        public BuyerDocumentDistributorData FindBy(DocumentVersionSignedByBuyer message)
        {
            return Persister.Get<BuyerDocumentDistributorData>("DocumentVersionId", message.DocumentVersionId.Value);
        }

        public BuyerDocumentDistributorData FindBy(DocumentVersionNoLongerRequiresSignature message)
        {
            return Persister.Get<BuyerDocumentDistributorData>("DocumentVersionId", message.DocumentVersionId.Value);
        }
    }
```

I've also asked this question on the NServiceBus Yahoo group: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/13265

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not give your endpointconfig, so I'm unsure which container you are using.

We experience the same (saga not getting persisted) when using the NinjectBuilder. Using the DefaultBuilder works ok.